# Mysql Query to Merge Two Condition Into One Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I just get confused. Already tried to search this whole site or google but didn't find the 'nearest' solution.

Ok let's say I have this table structure.

```
id date       finger_id finger_time is_enter
1  2017-03-30  2          09:00       1
2  2017-03-30  2          17:13       0
3  2017-03-31  4          09:10       1
4  2017-03-31  3          09:01       1
5. 2017-03-31  3          17:00       0
```

I want to make the table to be like below.

```
date       finger_id  enter_time  exit_time
2017-03-30   2        09:00       17:13
2017-03-30   4        09:10
2017-03-31   3        09:10       17:00
```

I have made sql statement but it turns like this.

```
date       finger_id  enter_time   exit_time
2017-03-30  2         09:00
2017-03-30  2                       17:13
2017-03-31  4         09:10
2017-03-31  3         09:01
2017-03-31  3                       17:00
```

I just want to know how to merge the is_enter 1 with is_enter 0 on the same date by the finger_id column.

Here's my sql query for the reference.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_fingerprint` 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_employee` ON `tbl_employee`.`fingerprint_id`=`tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_position` ON `tbl_position`.`position_id`=`tbl_employee`.`position_id` 
WHERE `fingerprint_date` >= '2017-03-01' 
AND `fingerprint_date` <= '2017-04-01' 
GROUP BY `tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_id`, 
         `tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_date`, 
         `tbl_fingerprint`.`is_enter` 
ORDER BY `fingerprint_date` ASC LIMIT 30
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `group by` `date` and `finger_id` fields and use conditional expression (`case` or `if()`) within an aggregate function to get the expected outcome. The conditional statements within the aggregate function make sure that they return value only if the right value is set in `is_enter` field. I leave out the employee details, since those do not form part of your question:

```
SELECT date, fingerprint_id, max(if(is_enter=1,finger_time,null) as enter_time, max(if(is_enter=0,finger_time,null) as exit_time
FROM `tbl_fingerprint` 
WHERE `fingerprint_date` >= '2017-03-01' 
AND `fingerprint_date` <= '2017-04-01' 
GROUP BY `tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_id`, 
         `tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_date`,  
ORDER BY `fingerprint_date` ASC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Man, this is great! I was just tried using max but I was stuck until I saw yours working great! Thank you so much. Edit: I just changed the max to min since I will get the low result, this is great!

Comment: Accepted, thank you for your help, but sorry I can't upvote your answer since I don't have the minimum reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_fingerprint`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_employee` ON `tbl_employee`.`fingerprint_id`=`tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_position` ON `tbl_position`.`position_id`=`tbl_employee`.`position_id`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_fingerprint WHERE is_enter = 0) a
    ON a.finger_id = tbl_fingerprint.finger_id AND a.date = tbl_fingerprint.date
WHERE `fingerprint_date` >= '2017-03-01' AND `fingerprint_date` <= '2017-04-01' AND tbl_fingerprint.is_enter = 1
GROUP BY `tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_id`, `tbl_fingerprint`.`fingerprint_date`, `tbl_fingerprint`.`is_enter`
ORDER BY `fingerprint_date` ASC LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This (This will work if `finger_time` is of `time` type):-

```
SELECT date, finger_id, min(finger_time) enter_time, if (min(finger_time) = max(finger_time), null, max(finger_time)) exit_time FROM xyz group by finger_id, date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a1.*, a3.time as time_out FROM attendance as a1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) as id FROM attendance where is_enter = '1' group by date, f_id ) as a2
ON a2.id = a1.id
LEFT JOIN attendance as a3 ON a3.date = a1.date AND a1.f_id = a3.f_id and a3.is_enter = '0'
```

you may need to cast the date to not include the time portion or to char with the yyyy-mm-dd format